# How to access private members of class to generate JSON Schema using JSON.net?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I'm using the code shown below to generate a JSON schema. However, it generates the schema using public members. Is there a way to do this using both private and public members?

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema schema = generator.Generate(type);
```

Comment: Have you created getters for those private members?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I have.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `JsonPropertyAttribute` to force the `DefaultContractResolver` to use my private field:

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator();
            JsonSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Person));
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        private string SecretName;

        public string PublicName { get; set; }
    }
```

The resulting schema has both `SecretName` and `PublicName`.

An alternative could also be to write a custom `IContractResolver` as shown [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm).

Note that I did this by looking at the schema generation code for the obsolete methods in JSON.net, but I assume it will work similarly for the separate package. As far as I know, the source code for that is not public.